# Python datetime code problem with format of time module

Tags: python, datetime

I used the %-I format for time, but it throws an error saying
"Traceback (most recent call last):
File "c:\Users\Lenovo\Desktop\VA Project\EDITH.py", line 31, in 
timeEve = now.strftime("%-I %M")
ValueError: Invalid format string"

```
import pyttsx3
import tkinter
import speech_recognition as sr
import datetime
import time
from datetime import date
today = date.today()
now =  datetime.datetime.now()

# Textual month, day and year   
d8 = today.strftime("%A %B %d, %Y")
time = now.strftime("%H%M")
timeDay = now.strftime("%M")
timeEve = now.strftime("%-I %M") #THIS IS WHERE THE PROBLEM IS WITH THE "%-I"

def askTime():
    engine = pyttsx3.init()
    engine.setProperty('rate', 170) # Decrease the Speed Rate x2
    if int(time)<1200:
        engine.say("Good morning!")
        engine.say("Today is "+d8)
        engine.say("and the time is "+timeDay)
        engine.runAndWait()
    if int(time)>1200 and int(time)<1600:
        engine.say("Good afternoon!")
        engine.say("Today is "+d8)
        engine.say("and the time is "+timeEve)
        engine.runAndWait()
    if int(time)>1600:
        engine.say("Good evening!")
        engine.say("Today is "+d8)
        engine.say("and the time is "+timeEve)
        engine.runAndWait()
```

Comment: If I remove the first 3 imports (which shouldn't be related to this issue), `timeEve` is computed w/o a problem.

Comment: that option is not available on all platforms (the [strftime cheat sheet](https://strftime.org/) mentions this explicitly); [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-format-codes) don't even list it anymore.

Comment: side note: if you use 12h clock, make sure to add am/pm for clarity, e.g. `"%I:%M %p"`

Comment: I want the voice to say "two PM", but if use %I it will say "zero two PM"